# Out-of-order delivery acknowledgements in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

In *manual-acknowledgement mode* (with `noAck=false`), messages may be acknowledged after being received and processed.  Using `IBasicConsumer`, the [.NET/C# API Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) suggests that this may be done, one-by-one, when a message is consumed:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

consumer.Received += (_, e) => 
    {
        // process the message...

        channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    };

string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

In my particular scenario, however, I need to consume **several** messages before I'm able to process them. And, in order to retain durability, I would have to acknowledge previous messages only later on (outside the scope of when they were received). These acknowledgements might also happen in a **different order** from the order in which messages are received.

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
var buffer = new List<BasicDeliverEventArgs>();

consumer.Received += (_, e) =>
{
    buffer.Add(e);

    if (TryProcess(buffer, out IList<BasicDeliverEventArgs> subset))
    {
        foreach (var p in subset)
        {
            channel.BasicAck(p.DeliveryTag, false);
            buffer.Remove(p);
        }
    }
};

string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

When I try this I only receive a few messages and then something blocks, which leads me to thinking that RabbitMQ does not support this. I've also used the channel's `BasicQos` method to bump up the `prefetchCount` to hundreds, but the number of messages I receive is still only 4 or 5.

Does RabbitMQ support out-of-order delivery acknowledgements? And if not, is there a better technique I can apply that uses RabbitMQ to provide the same durability?

Comment: RabbitMQ does support individual out-of-order message acks, but I'm not sure what is wrong with your code.

Comment: In my specific case, I want to continue receiving messages much further in advance before acking older messages. I suspect that the delivery tracking mechanism of RabbitMQ uses a basic sequence counter rather than identifying and tracking every individual message one-by-one, and would like more clarity on how this feature works.